# How to make Material-UI DataGrid row cliccable (and with pointer cursor), without the selection highlight?

Tags: material-ui

I'm using the community version of DataGrid from Material UI.

I've find the way to respond to row click using `onRowClick` prop, but I can't find a way to **disable the selection highlight** of a single cell and make the entire row with a **cursor pointer**:

```
<DataGrid disableSelectionOnClick={true} onRowClick={p => console.log('row clicked', p)} />
```

Isn't this feature available?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Might be a tad late but I came across the exact same need:

```jsx
<Datagrid
  ...
  sx={{
    // disable cell selection style
    '.MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
      outline: 'none'
    },
    // pointer cursor on ALL rows
    '& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Came to the same conclusion after posting this, then I forgot to answer to my own question!

Comment: If you want to use it with MUI v5 add the prefix to the classnames: `.v5-MuiDataGrid-cell:focus` and `.v5-MuiDataGrid-row:hover`